# Getting the full local path of a file in a site node in a webrole within a startup cmd file?

Tags: azure, cgi

It's been several hours lost now, i just don't get it.

Situation : 
- Migrating an ASP.net app to Azure
- IMPORTANT : This is a webrole with several websites, all websites are compiled in a folder "azure.builds" so my sites bindings are like 
physicalDirectory="..\azure.builds\www.mywebsite.com"
physicalDirectory="..\azure.builds\cb.mywebsite.com"
and so on

I have a cmd script that works great on my dev machine, which set permission on IIS to execute on an exe file (it has to be called by an html form).

Here is my local code startup.cmd which works against my local IIS :

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='MY_GCI', path='*.exe',verb='*',modules='CgiModule', scriptProcessor='c:\websites\myproject\azure.builds\cb.mywebsite.com\cgi-bin\mymodule.exe',resourceType='Either']"

On my html form the file is called via action "http://cb.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/mymodule.exe" and guess what it works.

But in my migration to Azure it doesn't, i'm unable to set permission to this particular file. The problem is i can't figure the full complete path to the EXE files as the example above show.

I tried this (%ROLEROOT%) :

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='MY_GCI', path='*.exe',verb='*',modules='CgiModule', scriptProcessor='%ROLEROOT%\azure.build\cb.mywebsite.com\cgi-bin\mymodule.exe',resourceType='Either']"

Does not work.
I studied several example involving similar CGI setup (such running PHP) but the difficulty is that the EXE module have to be exposed on http://cb.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/mymodule.exe wich is not even the main root webiste on my azure webrole, so this is not exactly the same.

Sorry if it is not very clear to understand, let say in short : how to find the full local path of a particular file in a particular site node in a webrole within a startup cmd file ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have this value outside of Azure:

scriptProcessor='c:\websites\myproject\azure.builds\cb.mywebsite.com\cgi-bin\mymodule.exe

Now you want the equivalent within Azure. The key for doing this is to use the ROLEROOT environment variable.

It appears you have considered ROLEROOT already, but perhaps there is a little bit off in mapping into your directory structure. I suggest you RDP into the Azure instance and get oriented (look at e:\approot for starters, but you are not guaranteed to always be there, thus the need for using ROLEROOT). RDP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx

If your real problem has to do with "...the difficulty is that the EXE module have to be exposed on http://cb.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/mymodule.exe wich is not even the main root webiste on my azure webrole, so this is not exactly the same." then I am not sure I can help as I am unsure of issue you are describing. But one idea: RDP in (as mentioned above) and try to execute the CGI script by hand in Azure and see how that goes. If that doesn't work, you may have a path or permission problem. If it *does* work, you still may have a problem related to permissions (since the RDP account will have more power than your default IIS user).

A couple of other things to try: Ensure your Azure Web Role is running with elevated permissions by using the following setting in ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<WebRole name="WebHost">    
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>
...
```

And also consider running your startup task elevated, also via ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

And, finally, some StartUp Task debugging tips:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas